# Multiple line itemLabel in apex:selectOption

Tags: visualforce, css, selectradio, selectoption

I have a situation that should be pretty easy, but I can't seem to make it work.

```
<apex:selectRadio id="restrictRadioBtns" layout="pageDirection" value="{!restrictedObjSettings.Restriction_Type__c}" >
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="{!$Label.RestrictionTypeNone}" itemLabel="{!$Label.RestrictionTypeNoneLabel}"/>
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="{!$Label.RestrictionTypeAttribute}" itemLabel="{!$Label.RestrictionTypeAttributeLabel1}"/>
                 <apex:outputText value="{!$Label.RestrictionTypeAttributeLabel2}"/>
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="{!$Label.RestrictionTypeList}" itemLabel="{!$Label.RestrictionTypeListLabel1}"/>
                 <apex:outputText value="{!$Label.RestrictionTypeListLabel2}"/>
            </apex:selectRadio>
```

I have three radio buttons, all with labels.
For the second and third radio buttons, I want to have two labels, a "header" in bold and 1.2em, and a paragraph of text below in non-bold and normal size.  Kind of like this:

[image]

I try to do this with outputTexts (above), but the outputTexts just end up above the selectRadio.

I tried the attribute itemEscaped = "false", which means I can add  and 
 to the itemLabel value, but if I add a div it doesn't seem to compile, plus it seems kind of ugly to do it this way.

Any tips?  I would rather use apex tags than raw HTML if possible.

Comment: Have you tried something like this : `<apex:selectOption itemValue="{!$Label.RestrictionTypeAttribute}" itemLabel="{!$Label.RestrictionTypeAttributeLabel1}<br/>{!$Label.RestrictionTypeAttributeLabel2}"/>` ?

Comment: Yes, as above I found that the <br/> works if I have itemEscaped = "false" but have not been able to add css to the first label and not the second.

Comment: You can wrap them in a `<div>` and apply inline css. Ex : `<apex:selectOption itemValue="{!$Label.RestrictionTypeAttribute}" itemLabel="<div style="font-weight: bold;">{!$Label.RestrictionTypeAttributeLabel1}</div><br/><div style="font-size: 14px;">{!$Label.RestrictionType‌​AttributeLabel2}</div>"/>`

Comment: It doesn't compile I'm afraid: "The value of attribute "itemLabel" associated with an element type "apex:selectOption" must not contains the '<' character."

Comment: I noticed that you can wrap the first instance of the expression in standard HTML tags but you can't apply any inline css nor add any other properties. So I've come up with something like this: `<apex:selectOption itemValue="" itemLabel="<h3>{!$Label.RestrictionTypeAttributeLabel1}</h3><br/><div style='font-size: 14px; padding-left: 25px; font-weight: bold;'>Secondary label</div>" itemEscaped="false" />` and then I applied the css for the first label by adding global rules on the page : `<style>h3 { color: red; font-size: 10px; }</style>`. Hope this helps

Comment: The above code works great, please add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed that you can wrap the first instance of the expression in standard HTML tags but you can't apply any inline css nor add any other properties. So I've come up with something like this:

```
<apex:selectOption itemValue="" itemLabel="<h3>{!$Label.RestrictionTypeAttributeLabel1}</h3><br/><div style='font-size: 14px; padding-left: 25px; font-weight: bold;'>Secondary label</div>" itemEscaped="false" />
```

and then I applied the css for the first label by adding global rules on the page :

```
<style>h3 { color: red; font-size: 10px; }</style>
```

Comment: I am trying to do as your suggest, however this error occurs:
The value of attribute "itemLabel" associated with an element type "apex:selectOption" must not contain the '<' character.